# Snap.svg - Rotate after drag not working

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

Hopefully this is a basic question and can be answered easily! Basically, I want to drag a shape then double click on it and rotate by 90deg. But once you move the shape from the start point the rotations go haywire. I have tried to recalculate the centre point for rotation like so...

```
var bbox = tri.getBBox();
tri.animate({
    transform: "R"+angle+"," + bbox.cx  + ","  + bbox.cy
}, 500)
```

See fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/henryJack/hsfor158/7/.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's potentially two issues.

Firstly, transforming will overwrite any existing transformations, so you want to include the existing transform and then include the new one on top of that.

```
element.transform()
```

Will give the existing transform in place. So you can combine the old with the new.

```
tri.animate({
   transform: tri.transform() + "R"+angle+"," + bbox.cx  + ","  + bbox.cy
}, 500)
```

However, the 2nd issue I think is that getBBox() doesn't take into account transforms by default, and it will accumulate transforms, so you may want to store the transform somewhere on a double click and use that instead of transform().

There is a hidden parameter to Snaps getBBox(), if you give it getBBox(1), I think it will take into account it's local transform (I may be wrong on this, so if you need to know definitely, I would ask a new question on this specific topic, as it may take a bit of digging through source code...the source code calls the parameter isWithoutTransform, but I think it depends how you interpret this, have a play).

So you can combine the two...

```
var bbox = tri.getBBox(1);
angle += 90;
tri.animate({
    transform: tri.transform() + "r"+angle+"," + bbox.cx  + ","  + bbox.cy
}, 500);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hsfor158/12/)

**Possible better solution**, there may be a better way though: If you need to take into account further transformations applied to outer elements (for example if its in a group which is transformed), it gets more complicated, and you will need to either add a function like getTransformedBBox OR maybe better, come up with an alternate solution, **for example to drag an outer group and rotate the inner element**. You could do this anyway as an alternate solution (add the element to a group, add the drag the group, but just rotate the element)!

2nd more reliable example by using an extra group

```
var triGroup = s.group( tri )
var angle = 0;
var rotate = function() {
    var bbox = tri.getBBox();
    angle += 90;
    bbox = tri.getBBox();
    tri.animate({
        transform: "r"+angle+"," + bbox.cx  + ","  + bbox.cy
    }, 500);
}

triGroup.dblclick(rotate);
triGroup.drag();
```

[jsfiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/hsfor158/13/)

Comment: Thanks @Ian , Amazing answer and quick response. I will post the game I have been trying to make if I finish it during my lunch break today!